# ploty r not able to plot when using layout()

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, plotly, line-plot

I have to plot some data. But when I use layout, I am not able to get anything in graph. If I remove it I will get graph plotted but sorted axis.I dont want sorted axis.

```
library(readxl)
library(plotly)
print("OK")
data_ = read_excel(path="Sample data.xlsx")
data_ = as.data.frame(data_)
Dates = c('Dec-17','Jan-18','Feb-18','Mar-18','Apr-18','May-18','Jun-18','Jul-18','Aug-18')

Dates_tb = as.data.frame(table(unlist(Dates)))

data_[3] = Dates_tb
KMS = data_[,1]
ax <- list(
  type = "category",
  categoryarray = Dates,
  categoryorder = "array",
  showgrid = TRUE,
  showline = TRUE,
  autorange = TRUE,
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  ticks = "outside",
  tickangle = 0
)

ay <- list(
 range = c(0,20000),
  dtick = 5000,
  showgrid = TRUE,
  showline = TRUE,
  autorange = FALSE,
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  ticks = "outside",
  tickangle = 0
)

plot_ly(data_,x = ~Dates, y = ~KMS,
         type = "scatter",
         mode = 'lines')%>%
layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay)
```

If I remove `layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay)` I will gt irregular graph.How to get proper graph with axis not sorted.

Comment: The layout function is an R base plotting function. Would have been surprised to see it as compatible with plotly.

Comment: now what should I do to get the graph working

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. ....

Comment: @42-, I thought the same, but there is `plotly::layout` which accepts the `xaxis=` and `yaxis=` arguments. As you suggested, though, it's rather difficult to troubleshoot without sample data. qwww, are you having trouble providing representative data? I'd think adding the output from `dput(head(data_,n=20))` into your question could suffice.